# How does 'super' works with multi-inheritance in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiple-inheritance, super

I have the following code:

```
class TestA(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(TestA, self).__init__()
        print 'TestA'

class TestB(object):
    def __init__(self, my_var=None):
        super(TestB, self).__init__()
        print 'TestB', my_var

class TestC(object):
    def __init__(self, my_var=None):
        super(TestC, self).__init__()
        print 'TestC', my_var

class TestD(TestB, TestA, TestC):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'TestD'
        super(TestD, self).__init__("Hello World")
```

And the output is

```
TestD
TestC None
TestA
TestB Hello World
```

I would expect to have :

```
TestD
TestB Hello World
TestA
TestC Hello World
```

It looks **super** get only the first parent.
When I have read one the [answer in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27134600/1066801) I thought it would do what I have expected.
What's wrong in my code or my understanding?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Each* method in the hierarchy needs to use super. See Raymond Hettinger's classic [`super` considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, I have updated my question because I have not fully understand the behavior of multi-inheritance. Any clues?